# Modify Woo-commerce product name as appears on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

(Site runs on Avada child+WP+woo)

Woo commerce product page has the product title as appears near the product image. 
I'm looking for a way to add the product name, one of it's attributes, e.g. "Disney's little princess - DVD" where "Disney's little princess" is the original product name and "DVD" is taken from one of the product attributes.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps

1. Place the woocommerce template files in your theme
2. Go to the file
   your template folder>Woocommerce >single-product>title.php
   Edit this file as you want